# ¿Cómo usar correctamente extras en un DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android

Antes usaba una `activity` y ahora estoy intentando utilizar `DialogFragment` pero estoy teniendo problemas al hacer esto, es el siguiente:

En `DialogFragment` no puedo obtener de la misma forma los *extras*, recibo este error:

> Error:(45, 18) error: cannot find symbol method getIntent()

```
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
        editTextNombre.setText(extras.getString("nombre"));
        editTextFecha.setText(extras.getString("fecha"));
        editTextZodiaco.setText(extras.getString("zodiaco"));
        editTextEdad.setText(extras.getString("edad"));
        editTextDiasrestantes.setText(extras.getString("diasrestantes"));
        ruta_imagen = extras.getString("ruta_imagen");
        imagenPersona.setImageBitmap(crearThumb());
    }
}
```

He estado mirando la documentación de Google pero no he conseguido nada, no comprendo bien como debo obtener los *extras* en un `DialogFragment`

Dejo aquí mi `DialogFragment`:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private TextView editTextNombre ,editTextFecha, editTextZodiaco, editTextEdad, editTextDiasrestantes;
    private ImageView imagenPersona;
    private Bundle extras;
    private String ruta_imagen; // La ruta de la imagen que el usuario eligio

    static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {

        return new MyDialogFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mas_informacion, container, false);

        editTextNombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre);
        editTextFecha = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextFecha);
        editTextZodiaco = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextZodiaco);
        imagenPersona = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagenPersona);
        editTextEdad = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextEdad);
        editTextDiasrestantes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextDiasrestantes);
        return view;


        // Recupera en un Objeto Bundle si tiene valores que fueron pasados como
        // parametro de una actividad.

        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
            editTextNombre.setText(extras.getString("nombre"));
            editTextFecha.setText(extras.getString("fecha"));
            editTextZodiaco.setText(extras.getString("zodiaco"));
            editTextEdad.setText(extras.getString("edad"));
            editTextDiasrestantes.setText(extras.getString("diasrestantes"));
            ruta_imagen = extras.getString("ruta_imagen");
            imagenPersona.setImageBitmap(crearThumb());
        }
    }
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se provoca porque `getIntent()` no es un método de alguna clase,

> error: cannot find symbol method getIntent()

Si te encuentras en una `Activity` puedes llamar el método `getIntent()` de esta forma:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Pero si te encuentras dentro de un `Fragment` o `DialogFragment`, usa como contexto la `Activity`:

```
Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
```